# Custom UIButton with PureLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, autolayout

I am using [SmileyBorg](https://twitter.com/smileyborg)'s [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) library for some Auto Layout magic.

How does one add a `UIButtonTypeCustom` ?

A normal button would be initialised with the following Pure Layout UIButton class method :

`self.myButton = [UIButton newAutoLayoutView];`

Custom `UIButtons` are initialised with

`UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Since I can't do something like

`self.myButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] newAutoLayoutView];`

And there is no 'buttonType' property to set post initialisation - how do I combine
these steps to create a custom UIButton in PureLayout?

Comment: By the way, note that the `+[UIView newAutoLayoutView]` method really just does one thing (aside from the regular instantiation): sets `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO. So don't be afraid to use a normal initializer, and then just add the line `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` afterwards. One more pro tip: whenever you call one of the `auto...` APIs on a UIView (such as `[view autoCenterInSuperview]`), the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property is automatically set to NO for the view you call the method on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIButton defaults to UIButtonTypeCustom so you will be able to use:

```
self.myButton = [UIButton newAutoLayoutView];
```

For fun, I suggest that you NSLog/printf `self.myButton.buttonType`!

Comment: Well - that's embarrassing. Cheers Justin that worked  - I had another piece of code that was hiding that.